# Plnkr controller not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like an extra input text field to appear above the add button upon click. 
However it does not work and the console is showing a reference error.

Starting out fresh in angular so I am a bit of a novice. Any help would be great. 
Thanks!

http://plnkr.co/edit/EFF63kpjiSg3EPQa7tkz?p=preview

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testViewer">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-snapshot/angular2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <label for="question">
    Question:
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Question Here" />
  </label>
  <br />
  <label for="answers">
    Correct Answers (optional):
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-default" ng-click="shortAnswer()">Add</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-default" ng-click="shortAnswer()">Delete</button>
  </label>
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="explanation">
    Explanation:
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Explanation Here" />
  </label>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
// Code goes here
  var app = angular.module("testViewer");

  var MainController = function($scope) {


                scope.shortAnswer = function () {

                    $('.add').click(function () {
                        var label = 1;
                        $(".content2").append('<label for="' + label + '"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""></label>');
                        label++;
                    });

                    $(".content2").on("click", ".remove", function () {
                        $(this).parent().remove();
                    });
                };
    };
     app.controller("MainController", MainController);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version of angular is having issue,  try to use the latest angular

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
```

and also in you userController , you need to inject $location and $anchorScroll

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/ASP5s8tq2Z4HSehktZJp?p=preview

**Edited**: Since by mistake wrong plunker link was added by OP

change you module creation line to this.

```
var app = angular.module("testViewer", []);
```

scope should be $scope

and you are mixing jquery and angular for event binding. In angular define method like this.

In Controller

```
      $scope.shortAnswer = function () {

              // your functionality

      };
```

In View

```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-default" ng-click="shortAnswer()">Add</button>
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/0110aobLh7WmbafWigyU?p=preview

Comment: I linked to the wrong plunkr! That solution worked however for the one I intended to link that solution did not. Any ideas?

Comment: @RyeGuy Whoops , ok let me see

Comment: @RyeGuy Updated the answer for second plunker as well.

Comment: I am fixing it now. I really appreciate the help

Comment: @RyeGuy Glad to help.Feel free to mark this as answer if it solves your original issue.

Comment: I definitely will once I get it functioning properly. Unfortunately the delete function does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include jquery file but used jquery functions. Include Jquery file above angularjs file injection.

you are using angularjs 1 code but called angularjs 2.

Comment: I included the jquery file. Nothing.

Comment: change the version first.

Comment: you are using angularjs 1 code but called angularjs 2.

Comment: If I wanted it to comply with angular2, what changes would I make?

Comment: refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element . you can use most of jquery function in jqlite in angularjs

Comment: angular 2 and angular 1 is complete different. I don't have knowledge on angular 2. I'm also going to learn

Answer (score 1):

"VM332 angular.js:8296 TypeError: $transclude is not a function"

Error is coming because you implemented ng-view in wrong way.
read Doc- 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your current code isn't working, but the convention in AngularJS is to use the ng-show and ng-hide directives.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-default" ng-click="shortAnswer('add')">Add</button>
<label for="lblName"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-show="showLabel"></label>
```

Controller:

```
scope.shortAnswer = function (btnVal) {
    if (btnVal == 'add') {
        $scope.showLabel = true;
    }
```

Now, I'm not sure that this is actually the best way to do it, but I assume you want both buttons to call your function shortAnswer().

Comment: I appreciate the input. However they have to be able to add an infinite number of input elements.

Comment: I'd say that's still doable with some tweaking, but it might get messy, and your implementation makes sense. What's not clear to me is why you're even using Angular here - will you be adding more to your controller? I guess your questions will be linked to ng-models?